# send pandas dataframe as csv file to slack without saving

Tags: python, pandas, slack

I want to post to slack the result of a Pandas dataframe `to_csv()` method as a file, but slack SDK `files_upload()` expects a filename in parameter `file`. This is my code:

```
from slack_sdk import WebClient

client = WebClient(os.environ["slack_token"])

csv_file = df.to_csv()

response = self.client.files_upload(
    file=csv_file,
    initial_comment=message_text,
    thread_ts=thread_ts,
)
```

The problem with this code is that the method takes the file contest as the filename and raises an error because it can't find the file.

Is there any way I can send the text content of the variable as a file?

Answer (score 1):

[StringIO Module in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stringio-module-in-python/)
"The StringIO module is an in-memory file-like object. This object can be used as input or output to the most function that would expect a standard file object."

```py
csv_file = StringIO(df.to_csv())

response = self.client.files_upload(
    file=csv_file,
    initial_comment=message_text,
    thread_ts=thread_ts,
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting this error with your solution: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: try `BytesIO`, the binary complement. `csv_file = BytesIO(df.to_csv().encode())`.